# Most recent date

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

Here is my table

```
Livraison
number  date
1       3/06/2001
2       4/06/2001
3       8/07/2002
```

I want to get the most recent date out of that table and show is number in a table.

What I have right now which doesn't work ...

What is wrong?

```
/
SELECT number,date
FROM Livraison
order by date desc
limit 1
/
```

giving me error:

> ORA - 00933

at line 4 which is limit

Data type in date is DATE data type in number is integer.

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work?  Are you getting an error? Are you not getting the result you expected? What are the data types of those columns?

Comment: I did an edit on whats happening !

Comment: Your question was tagged MySQL.  MySQL does not produce "ORA" errors; Oracle does.  I changed the tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`:

```
select number, date
from Livraison
order by date desc
fetch first 1 row only;
```

In Oracle:

```
select l.*
from (select number, date
      from Livraison
      order by date desc
     ) l
where rownum = 1;
```

Comment: Your question was tagged MySQL and the answer used MySQL syntax.  Apparently, you are using Oracle, so I changed the answer.

Comment: Sorry im quite new at all this thanks a lot for you quick answer :) !